# Show that $1000000! \equiv 500001 \mod 1000003$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working in the following exercise:

> Show that $1000000! \equiv 500001 \mod 1000003$

Trying to find a way to apply Wilson's theorem I'm trying the following:

\begin{align*}
1000002! &\equiv -1 \mod 1000003!\\
1000002\cdot1000001! &\equiv -1 \mod 1000003!\\
1000002\cdot1000001\cdot1000000! &\equiv -1 \mod 1000003!\\
(-1)\cdot1000001\cdot1000000! &\equiv -1  \mod 1000003!
\end{align*}

This is as close as I've been able to be to the exercise, I don't know what path to follow to reach that $ 500001 $, any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $1000001\equiv-2\pmod{1000003}$.

Comment: All of those should be mod $1000003$ - not mod the factorial.

Comment: It should also be clear that one should mention the fact that $1000003$ is a prime. - For example, with an additional digit, we have $10000000!\equiv 0\pmod {10000003}$ instead

Comment: $1000002! \equiv \pmod{100003}$ is not that exciting a remark.  It doesn't need an exclamation point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate 2000! (mod 2003)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362370/calculate-2000-mod-2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed,
$$2\cdot1000000!\equiv1000000!\cdot1000001\cdot1000002=1000002!\equiv-1\pmod{1000003}$$

Now, the inverse of 2 $\pmod{1000003}$ is $\frac{1000004}{2}=500002$.
So,
$$1000000!\equiv-1\cdot500002=-500002\equiv500001\pmod{1000003}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$500\,001\cdot 2\equiv -1$$

Comment: It's 1 000 003, not 100 003.

Comment: @jmerry I just recounted the zeroes and saw that.

Answer (score 1):

The next step? $1000001\equiv -2\mod 1000003$. Now, you just have to divide $-1$ by $(-1)\cdot (-2)=2$.