# What is the remainder of $65!$ divided by $67$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the remainder of $65!$ divided by $67$?

---

**Attempt:**

By Wilson's theorem, we have $66! = -1\mod(67) $.

$$66! = -1\mod(67) \implies 66 (65!) = -1 \mod(67)$$

and we also know that $66 = -1 \mod(67)$, then we have
$$66 (65!) = -1 \mod(67) \implies -65! = -1 \mod (67)$$

so the remainder is 1. Is this the only approach?

Comment: You certainly can compute $65!$ and divide it by $67$ to get the result.  You can reduce each multiplication $\bmod 67$ as you go.

Comment: I'm certain it's not the *only* approach, but it's certainly a very good one. What are you looking for?

Comment: The best approach you can use.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I would have no other idea, but I also cannot see a motivation to find another approach. What don't you like with the approach you used ?

Comment: See for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1362370/11619) or many threads [in this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Wilson%27s%20theorem). In other words, yes, Wilson is the way to go. What do you feel is wrong about it?

Comment: A general reflection formula is discussed e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23823/11619). Many candidates. I would like to call this a duplicate, but I am uncertain about the choice of a target. An aspect worth knowing is [Wilson's theorem in abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization).

Answer (score 2):

$66!\equiv 66\bmod 67\implies 65!\equiv 1\bmod 67$

You could use $$65!\equiv -((33!)^2)\bmod 67$$ But then it comes down to finding 33! mod 67.

There are probably even more methods, But none is as quick as realizing $${ -1 \over -1}\equiv 1$$ Which is what Wilson's Theorem tells us.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most natural approach. Since you seem to be seeking different methods I will mention a generalization ([Wilson Reflection Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24131/242)) from a slightly different viewpoint.

An equivalent way to state Wilson's theorem is that any complete system of representatives of nonzero remainders mod $\,p\,$ has product $\equiv -1.\,$ In particular this is true for any sequence of $\,p\,$ consecutive integers, after removing its $\rm\color{#c00}{multiple}$ of $\,p.\,$ Thus the standard remainder sequence when left-shifted by $\,k\,$  i.e.  $\,{-}k,\ldots,-1,\require{cancel}\cancel{\color{#c00}0,} 1,2,\ldots,\, p\!-\!1\!-\!k\,$ has product $\,(-1)^k k!\, (p\!-\!1\!-\!k)!\equiv -1\pmod{\!p},\, $ so

$$\qquad\qquad (p\!-\!1\!-\!k)!\, \equiv\, \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}\! \pmod{\!p}\qquad [\text{Wilson  Reflection Formula}]$$

The OP is the special case $\, k = 1\,$ (leftshift by $1)$

**Remark** $\ $ The essence of Wilson's theorem is group-theoretical, so if you know a little group theory I highly recommend that you look at some [prior posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+Wilson+group) on the group-theoretic viewpoint, which more clearly highlight the innate [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29) symmetry (negation/inversion "reflection")

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that in the field $\mathbb{F}_{67}$, the only elements that are their own (multiplicative) inverses are $1$ and $66$.  So the elements $2, 3, ..., 65$ can be paired off into inverse pairs.  Each pair multiplies to $1$.

Having said that: That idea is often used as a proof of Wilson's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Every number in the range $[1,66]$ has a multiplicative inverse because 67 is prime. Also, the equation $x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{67}$ can be written as $(x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{67}$. SInce 67 is prime, the only solutions are 1 and 66. This means that the range [2, 65] is composed of 32 pairs of numbers, where each pair of numbers are each other's multiplicative inverse

It follows that $65! \equiv 1 \pmod{67}$