# Efficient way to find the remainder when $2001+ 2002+ 2003+ … + 2015+ 2016$ is divided by $2017$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I can think of a couple of ways

1. Notice that unit digit of the first $8$ terms can be added in the last $8$ terms to make them $2017$. Now add the first $8$ terms without their unit digits (i.e. $2000*8$) and find a remainder on that.
2. Sum of AP series = $4017*8$, now find the remainder

But both would take a lot of computation.
Is there any more efficient way of doing it manually?

Comment: why not work with negative remainders?

Comment: $-16-15-14-...-1=-16*17/2=-8*17=-136\equiv1881\bmod2017$

Comment: BTW, the sum should be $4017*8$.

Comment: I wouldn't call $4017 \cdot 8$ a lot of computation.  It is only four single digit multiplies, one of them including $0$, and a few carries.  Using the negative remainders seems a bit easier to me, but not much.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand your point-of-view, but it's all relative. It does seem like 'a lot of computation' to a grade 6 student who gets an average of 1 minute to do a question like this in a math competition. Also, a few seconds saved here can be used on another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $-16-15-14-...-1=-16\times17/2=-8\times17=-136\equiv1881\bmod2017$.

Comment: Thanks. This question is solved. Can you please recommend some related topics to learn more about questions related to this? Any pointer to a source would be awesome :)

Comment: Consider 'Elementary number theory' by David M Burton.

Comment: @NickP See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3342046/242) for a multiplicative analog (generalization of Wilson's formula). Generally working with a [*least magnitude* residue system](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20%22least%20magnitude%22) simplifies modular arihmetic. This answer is a special case of such.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE:

$2001 \equiv -16 \mod (2017)$

$2002 \equiv -15 \mod (2017)$

$2003 \equiv -14 \mod (2017)$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$2016 \equiv -1 \mod (2017)$

Summing these relations we get:

$2001+2002+2002+2003+ . . . 2016 \equiv-\frac{16(1+16)}2=-136 \mod(2017)\equiv 1881 \mod(2017)$

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to:
2016(2017)(1/2)-(2000)(2001)(1/2)
2016(2017)(1/2)≡0(mod 2017)

2000(2001)(1/2)=(1000)(2001)≡(1000)(-16)≡-16000 (mod 2017)
-16000 (mod 2017)≡-136(mod 2017)≡1881(mod 2017)